# jQuery find not working for select="selected"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I get all selected options from a `<select>` using [jQuery](https://jquery.com/)?

```
<select id="mySelector" ... >
<option value="1" selected="selected">option1</option>
<option value="2" selected="selected">option2</option>
<option value="3">option3</option>
</select>
```

I tried `$('#mySelector').find(":selected")`. It returns `[]`.

But if my options have only `selected` property instead of `selected="selected"`  `$('#mySelector').find(":selected")` returns the correct results.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

There is little difference between *attributes* and *properties*.

1. Attributes does have assigned values like `attr="value"`.
2. While properties are just a property which does not have any value assigned like `checked, selected etc.`.

---

so to answer your question i would say then you have to use `.map()` iterations to create array:

```
var arr = $('#mySelector option').map(function(){
    return $(this).attr('selected') === "selected"    
}).get();
```

Comment: So how do I add a property selected instead of selected="selected" using jQuery?

Comment: @JaseemAbbas check my answer

Answer (score 1):

Setting the attribute `selected="selected"` will work as a pre-selected option and will be displayed first in the drop-down list.

However, I guess the user chooses something and you want to get that value.

```
$('select option:selected').each(function () {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Iterate through each one in the select element and with the pseudo selector `:selected` just get it's value.

[JsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/e6vLhrad/3/)

> Note: If you instead want the text, not the value, use `.text()` instead of `.val()`

Answer (score 1):

You can try both, one after another:

```
$('#mySelector').find(":selected")//animate...
$('#mySelector').each(function(){
    if ($(this).attr('selected') === "selected"){
        //animate...
    }
}
```